# If I stop running a Tor relay, does my IP address keep "marked" as running it? How do I disable a relay completely?

Tags: relays, ip-address

As of late I was experimenting with running a non-exit Tor relay from my home IP address. However, after setting it all up and having it successfully running, I became aware of the dangers of traffic of illegal content, being blacklisted from sites that identify you as running a Tor relay (which I didn't know it could be done that easily)...

In https://exonerator.torproject.org/ my internal host doesn't appear as having run a relay. Should I worry about my IP address being "marked" by any website I have visited? How do I disable a relay completely?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

By the way, I have a Dynamic DNS but I didn't configure the relay as such, so every time I restart my router I have a new IP address. This is good for me, isn't it? Or is it the Default Route blacklisted from such websites?